# Select List From Database With Parameter

Tags: php, session, laravel

Hi there i have some problem getting list from database using laravel 4.1

I have session that stored some value about companyid. Then i want to print the list to table based on the companyid itself. Let say i can access the session using `{{ Session::get('name')}}`

This is my controller index()

```
public function index($cid) {

        $pengguna = User::where('id_company', '=', $cid)->get();
        $pengguna->toarray();

        $data = array(
            'pengguna' => $pengguna,
            'page' => 'master',
            'index' => 0
        );

        return View::make('console.pengguna')->with($data);
    }
```

then i want to print the data to table in view

```
                @if($pengguna->count())
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table_pengguna_list">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>No</th>
                        <th>Firstname</th>
                        <th>Lastname</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Last Login</th>
                        <th class="td-actions">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           @foreach ($pengguna as $pgn)
                           <tr>
                               <td>{{ $index++ }}</td>
                               <td>{{ $pgn->firstname }}</td>
                               <td>{{ $pgn->lastname }}</td>
                               <td>{{ $pgn->username }}</td>
                               <td>{{ $pgn->email }}</td>
                               <td>{{ $pgn->level }}</td>
                               <td>{{ $pgn->updated_at }}</td>
                           </tr>
                           @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
           ....
```

how to pass the parameter from session to the controller then? so basically pass the `{{ Session::get('name')}}` to `$cid` in index controller.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

hi there i have found the solution, just place refactor the index controller to;

```
public function index() {
        $cid = Session::get('name');
        $pengguna = User::where('id_company', '=', $cid)->get();
        $pengguna->toarray();

        $data = array(
            'pengguna' => $pengguna,
            'page' => 'master',
            'index' => 0
        );

        return View::make('console.pengguna')->with($data);
    }
```